# How do I use a model field inside a queryset for a modelchoicefield?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-queryset

I want to be able to seat a party at table.  First I need to display the form, so I create the model form with a extra field called open_tables.  This has to be every table marked AVAILABLE that has the capacity.  The problem is that I don't know how to reference the number_in_party field from the queryset.  I've tied self.base_fields, but self doesn't work.  I've tried SeatPartyForm.model.number_in_party, that doesn't work.  This is happening on the get, and number_in_party is filled at this point.  Is there any way to do this query?

```
class SeatPartyForm( ModelForm):

open_tables = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Table.objects.filter(status__exact=Table.AVAILABLE).exclude(max_capacity__lt =  model.base_fields['number_in_party']))
class Meta:
    model = Party
    fields = ('name', 'number_in_party')`
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't know the actual `number_in_party` before user fills in one. The server-side Django form cannot do the limitation automatically for you.

Thus you need to either change `open_tables` after `number_in_party` is available, via javascript; or split the form to two parts, in the first part user fills in `number_in_party`, in the second part, in server side you could filter `open_tables` according to the ready value of `number_in_party`.

Comment: This is on the get, and it's the interpreter that's causing the issues.  I also updated the question, at the point this is being used number_in_party is already set.